# lowercasing all entries when signing up w/ Parse using PFSignupViewController

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm using the default signup/login view controllers that Parse.com provides.

I have it working, but I want the textFields to responded lowercase all entries and if possible use underscore(_) for spaces.

I've been medling with this for the past day but haven't found anything useful on the web.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

var logInViewcontroller: PFLogInViewController! = PFLogInViewController()
var signUpViewController: PFSignUpViewController! = PFSignUpViewController()

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil){
        self.logInViewcontroller.fields = PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFields.LogInButton | PFLogInFields.SignUpButton | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten | PFLogInFields.DismissButton
        self.logInViewcontroller.delegate = self            
        self.signUpViewController.delegate = self
        self.logInViewcontroller.signUpController = self.signUpViewController
        self.logInViewcontroller.logInView?.usernameField!.delegate = self
    } else {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("logedIn", sender: self) //use found: moving forward
    }
    presentViewController(self.logInViewcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)        
}

func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController, shouldBeginSignUp info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController, didSignUpUser user: PFUser) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I've set a UITextFieldDelegate so, but not sure how to connect the two.
I think i'm suppose to use this...

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if (textField == self.logInViewcontroller.logInView?.usernameField) { 
        textField.text = textField.text.lowercaseString
        return false // false or true?
    }
}
```

Has anyone else came across this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using UITextField delegate you can add a target to your textfield for the control event editing changed:

in viewDidAppear

instead of this"

```
self.logInViewcontroller.logInView?.usernameField!.delegate = self
```

add this:

```
self.logInViewcontroller.logInView?.usernameField.addTarget(self, action: "textChanged:", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
```

and add your method to manipulate the string:

```
func textChanged(sender: UITextField) {
    sender.text = sender.text!.lowercaseString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "_")
}
```

BTW Leo is here. :)

Comment: beautiful code you go there. It worked. Though, for the replacing I had to use: .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "_", options: nil, range: nil). And lol two Leo's chatting. thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make your modifications at the end, because the user may not notice and you might make some changes that mean they are unable to use the account that was just created in future. The user should always know exactly what the login details are. So, make the changes as each character is typed. Do that with `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`. To connect the delegate you should be getting the `logInView` from the `logInViewcontroller`, which is an instance of `PFLogInView` and has properties for the `usernameField` etc (which you are using, but you need to check that the `usernameField` has been created and ensure that the view gets loaded if it doesn't yet).